# How to list available containers in SWIFT using JCloud?

Tags: java, openstack, openstack-swift, jclouds

Can someone tell how to list available containers in Openstack SWIFT using Jcloud ? We have used keystone for authentication.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the portable abstraction, you can list all containers with `BlobStore.list`.  Note that this differs from `BlobStore.list(String)`, which lists blobs within a container.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a complete Swift example, read the [OpenStack: Getting Started Guide for jclouds](http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/openstack/). It has an example for listing containers.